# Openning Sim Toolkit using Kotlin Android Devlopment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I want my app to open sim card toolkit so that a user can make payments via mobile provided in the sim toolkit application Please help. Kotlin

I am trying to use intents but i don't know exactly how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun launchSTK(activity: Context) {
    
    val intent = activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.stk")
    if (intent == null) {
        try {
            val intent1 = Intent()
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent1.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
            intent1.action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
            intent1.type = "text/plain"
            intent1.component =
                ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity")
            activity.startActivity(intent1)
            return
        } catch (activitynotfoundexception: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        }
    } else if (intent == null) {
        try {
            val intent2 = Intent()
            intent2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            intent2.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
            intent2.action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
            intent2.type = "text/plain"
            intent2.component = ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkMain")
            activity.startActivity(intent2)
            return
        } catch (activitynotfoundexception1: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        }
    } else if (intent == null) {
        val intent3 = Intent()
        intent3.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent3.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
        intent3.action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
        intent3.type = "text/plain"
        intent3.component = ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkLauncherActivity")
        activity.startActivity(intent3)
    } else if (intent == null) {
        val intent4 = Intent()
        intent4.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent4.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
        intent4.action = "android.intent.action.MAIN"
        intent4.type = "text/plain"
        intent4.component = ComponentName("com.android.stk", "com.android.stk.StkMain")
        activity.startActivity(intent4)
    } else if (intent == null) {
        val launchIntent5 =
            activity.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mediatek.StkSelection")
        activity.startActivity(launchIntent5)
    } else {
        activity.startActivity(intent)
    }
    return
}
```